# XML to HTML Tool

Tags: xml

I need to make a tool that a user can past giant XML data into a textbox, press a button, and display is similar to this http://codecanyon.net/item/jsonviewer-a-user-friendly-data-viewer/full_screen_preview/6491585

I can program it but not entirely sure the best way to go about doing this.  I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual tool for applying style to XML -- either to produce another XML document, or to produce HTML -- would be an XSLT Stylesheet. Of course you'd have to write the rules to tell it how you want the XML rendered, but a bit of websearching on "xslt html tree" will probably find an example you can modify. If not, I'm sure this is one of the things covered on [Dave Pawson's xsl faq website](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/)

Though depending on just how "giant" a document is, that may not work -- XSLT normally reads the whole document into memory before processing it, and "streaming" XSLT subset processors are very rare. If the document is large enough, you may find that you're better off using an XML parser that generates events (a SAX parser, for example) and hand-coding the mapping from events coming in to HTML going out.

Comment: Hi Keshlam, thank you for responding this was exactly what I was looking for. The XML file is rather large, probably 50k lines roughly. Sometimes quite  few less, sometimes more. Another problem is, the XML tags and values are pretty much random.

I will look into the SAX parser THANKS!!!!